# Hidden status bar still takes up space

Tags: android

Is this the way system suppose to behave?

I've hidden it according to official docs and then I added simple view programmatically with match parent widht, 50dp height and some background color.

There is a blank space between view and the upper edge of the screen whose height corresponds to status bar height.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're setting the visibility to GONE and not INVISIBLE. When it's "GONE" it won't take up space in the UI.

Comment: Are you sure that GONE works with status bar. This is how UIOptions should be set acording to docs:
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN (this hides status bar but it still takes up space)
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN (this doesnt hide it but status bar doesnt takes place also)
There I few more options, I need to test them yet

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you're talking about the status bar. You've followed the approach for your target version of Android (including hiding the ActionBar too) described here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html  right?

Comment: Yes correct, and I'm testing on S3 currently running on Android 4.3